# how to show $\frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial x}=F_1(x,y,z)$ using the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

If $\displaystyle f(x,y,z)= \int_c (F\,dl)=\cdots=\int_0^x (F_1(t,0,0)\,dt)+\int_0^y (F_2(x,t,0)\,dt)+\int_0^z (F_3(x,y,t)\,dt)$

Why  $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=F_1(x,y,z)$ ?

My attempt:  differentiating in respect to x the last terms from the above equation are zero since neither varies with respect to x,to the first term we can make
$F_1(x,0,0)=G(x)$ and
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x G(t)=G(x)=F_1(x,0,0)=\frac{\partial f(x,0,0)}{\partial x}$$

I just prove for f(x,0,0) how I change something  so that I prove to $f(x,y,z)$ or $\partial f(x,y,z)/\partial x=F_1(x,y,z)$ ?

Thank you

Comment: I already know how to do it with respect to z

Comment: You cannot ignore the last two integrals without further justification. Are you saying that $F_2,F_3$ are independent of $x$?

Comment: copper.hat Yes. isn't that enough?

Comment: Just to make sure, are you saying that ${\partial F_2(x,y,z) \over \partial x} = 0$ (and same for $F_3$)?

Comment: No that is not zero at least for the general case ,I am saying for the integral that varies from 0 to y and 0 z.I am trying to prove that as well but I am not getting that so far equal to zero

Comment: See Alex's answer below. The result is called the Leibniz rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that if the field is conservative, you can instead of choosing a path $(0,0,0)\to (x,0,0)\to (x,y,0)\to (x,y,z)$ like in your post, choose a path $(0,0,0)\to (0,y,0)\to (0,y,z)\to (x,y,z)$. In this case you'll get for some function $G(y,z)$, that $$f=G(y,z)+\int_0^x F_1(t,y,z)dt$$ much like in your equation in the original post.
so that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=F_1$ follows immediately.

Comment: Yes ,so obvious now,thank you again

Answer (score 0):

The reasoning is false. The second two integrals do depend on $x$, so the correct partial derivative gives:

$$\frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial x}=F_1(x,0,0)+\int_0^y\frac{\partial F_2(x,t,0)}{\partial x}dt+\int_0^y\frac{\partial F_3(x,t,0)}{\partial x}dt$$

Do you have other conditions for this problem? It looks like you're evaluating a line integral first along the $x$ axis, then along the $y$ axis, then along the $z$ axis.

I don't see how your question is related to what you're trying to prove: that two line integrals with the same endpoints have the same value if the vector field is conservative. For two line integrals between two endpoints, write them as $\int_{c_1}F(x(t),y(t),z(t))dt$, $\int_{c_2}F(x(t),y(t),z(t))dt$, where $c_1,c_2$ have the same endpoints. Notice that if you *reverse* $c_2$ (the integration direction along $c_2$, then

$$\int_{c_1}F(x(t),y(t),z(t))dt+\int_{-c_2}F(x(t),y(t),z(t))dt=0,$$

since you're now integrating along a loop. But reversing $c_2$ is equivalent to changing $t\rightarrow -t$, which means that $\int_{-c_2}F(x(t),y(t),z(t))dt=-\int_{c_2}F(x(t),y(t),z(t))dt$. So you get the desired conclusion.

Comment: I am seeing a prove for why the definitions of conservative vector field are true, it starts from a statement that a close curve of a line integral is zero,from this prove two line integrals are equal if have the same end and start points ,after this is where I am stuck to understand , knowing the before statement then it is prove that F=gradf

Comment: And yes that is true

Comment: How do I prove that the RHS of the above equation is equal to F_1(x,y,z)? because is the condition I must arrive

Comment: @KellyBlunie: see new second paragraph.

Comment: I type it wrong, ariving to the conclution that 2 curves with the same end and start points then using f(x,y,x)=$\int_c F.ds $ it is arrive to the conclusion that gradf=F however in this prove skip one step and that is I don't quite understand so far,I partially understand.